# Using the continue statement in a for loop

Tags: javascript

Why does the `continue` statement print even numbers, but will print odd numbers if replaced by `console.log()` in the following?

```js
// print even numbers
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  if ((i % 2) != 0) {
    continue;
  }
  console.log(i);
}

//print odd numbers
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  if ((i % 2) != 0) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to do something else? Are you expecting the two snippets to do the same?

Comment: I recommend using the debugger built into your browser or IDE to step through the code statement by statement. Using a debugger isn't something reserved for experienced programmers it's basically the first thing I suggest learning after "Hello, JavaScript." There's nothing more informative than watching exactly what happens to the flow of execution.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, the loop continues with the next iteration if the number is odd (and therefore the program does not reach `console.log()`). In this next iteration the number is even and will be printed.

The second example is quite trivial: you only print the number if it is odd.

Answer (score 0):

When the `continue` statement is executed, the rest of the contents of the loop body are skipped and execution returns to the top of the loop, to start the next iteration of the loop. So this:

```
if ((i % 2) != 0) {
  continue;
}
```

means "If `i` is odd, skip back to the top of the loop, don't execute the rest of the loop body." That means the odd number isn't printed.

In your second example, you're only outputting when the condition is true, so you've ended up doing the opposite output, but in a different way: Only calling `console.log` when the number is odd.

You can make the first one output only even numbers by removing the `continue`, changing the condition, and moving `console.log` into the `if` body:

```js
// print even numbers
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  if ((i % 2) === 0) { // *** Changed condition
    console.log(i);    // *** Moved `console.log`
  }
}
```

That does even numbers in the same basic way the second one did odd numbers.

Or you can change the second one work like the first one, but in general it's best to avoid using `continue` (there are probably exceptions to that general rule):

```js
// print odd numbers
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  if ((i % 2) == 0) { // *** Changed condition
    continue;
  }
  console.log(i);
}
```